# in linux screen how do you turn off the status tab?

Tags: gnu-screen

Is there a way in screen to turn off the status bar? Ideally, only display it when I have 2+ tabs open? What `.screenrc` entries would accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can get a "status bar" that I can think of:

One status bar is the `caption`.  It normally only appears with multiple windows (split screen), this setting is `caption splitonly`.  The always-there version is `caption always`.  It doesn't seem to have a way to tie it to the number of screens ("tabs") open.   If it goes away by hitting your command character (^a) and typing `:caption splitonly` then that was what you're looking at, and putting  `caption splitonly` in your .screenrc will get rid of it.

The other status bar is the `hardstatus` which refers to the terminal's "hardware status" line.  This one *usually* gets displayed in the title bar of your window, but it could be forced to the bottom of the terminal with the setting `hardstatus alwayslastline`.  Setting `hardstatus off` turns it off.  This is always either "on" or "off".

Comment: sweet!  "caption splitonly" is exactly what I wanted.  Knowing about the vim-style <escape-key> + ":caption splitonly" was bonus, too.

Comment: It looks like you can't disable it entirely.. .which is a shame as I wanted to be able to split screen two dialog boxes on a tiny LCD... the wasted line for the caption is unacceptable unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

The setting to turn off the `hardstatus` line is called `ignore`. The `off` setting doesn't do what one would expect it to do, the manual says:

> If the flag is set to ‘off’, these messages are overlaid in reverse video mode at the display line.

I have this in my `.screenrc`, which seems to do what you need:

```
hardstatus ignore
```

Comment: Hi Bert!  Welcome to Server Fault.  Thanks for adding this answer.  When quoting someone it is good to add a link to the source.

Comment: Didn't work either there's still a line saying "[freebsd][                                                     0$ bash  1-$ bash  2$ bash  3$ bash  (4*$ bash)                                                      ][01/22/22 12:56 AM]" at the bottom of my screen

Comment: If you already have "hardstatus ignore" and "caption splitonly" as suggested in the other reply, I would not know what could cause this, sorry. You may want to have a look at your systemwide screenrc for clues (on FreeBSD, that seems to be /usr/local/etc/screenrc).